# .htaccess rewrite example.com/store/page.html to domain.com/page.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Just migrated a website to a different platform.

Old site had urls like,

https://www.example.com/store/product.html

https://www.example.com/store/product2.html

https://www.example.com/store/product3.html

New site has urls like,

https://www.example.com/product.html

https://www.example.com/product2.html

https://www.example.com/product3.html

How can I 301 redirect the old urls to the new layout format of the new site using htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this rule in your htaccess, which should be in root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```